# False "CREATE SEQUENCE" lines of h2 SCRIPT command

Tags: java, h2

In my java application I backup certain tables with the SCRIPT command. When I try to restore this generated backup script into the existing database I get the error

```
Sequence "SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_6DBC2231_8C34_46B3_9CB9_2BC9E42CECA2" already exists
```

It seems that the "SCRIPT" command is generating a "CREATE SEQUENCE" line for every system sequence in the database. Not only for the sequences of the tables selected for backup, but for all sequences of all tables. So on restore the backup script tries to create the sequences for the untouched tables and fails. Of course.

Is this a bug in the SCRIPT command or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also asked on GitHub:
[#2094](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2094).
This is a copy of some my comments from the mentioned issue for other readers:

`SCRIPT` is not a backup command, it's a data / metadata export command. You can use it for backup purposes, however. But you need a new empty database to load such scripts into it.

It exports all sequences from all schemas or only from specified schema(s) by design.

1. You can use the `DROP` clause of the [`SCRIPT`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#script) command. With this clause the additional `DROP TABLE` commands will be included into such script. `DROP TABLE` command also drops automatically created sequences of generated columns.
2. You can execute the `DROP ALL OBJECTS` command before the `RUNSCRIPT` command.
3. You can close all connections, delete the database, create a new one and execute the `RUNSCRIPT` in it.

Comment: But how can I backup and restore a single table then?

Comment: Backup procedure is for the whole database. However, you can try to use `SCRIPT NOSETTINGS DROP TABLE tableName TO 'fileName.sql'`. It exports users (with `IF NOT EXISTS` clause), drop command for the specified table, create table statement for it, and its data. You can also specify multiple tables separated with comma.

Comment: Even with "NOSETTINGS" the SCRIPT command still exports all the sequences of all tables.

Comment: My solution was to import the backup script into a new database. Then - in the original database - I link the backed up tables with [CREATE LINKED TABLE](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_linked_table). Finally I DELETE all rows in the original table and copy the linked table data into the original table with: `INSERT INTO backedup_table AS (SELECT * FROM linked_table)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it's bug in `SCRIPT` command, As it says...

> Creates a SQL script from the database.

So when you created sequences first time make sure it don't create sequence if it exist with something like below.

`CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS`

Then `SCRIPT` command should copy same while backing up scripts.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` clause is not preserved, it affects only the current execution of the command.

Comment: The bug is that SCRIPT exports all auto generated sequences of all tables. Even if you chose only certain tables. That makes restoring into the same DB impossible. Because the sequences of the not exported tables already exist.